# Yii framework proposed folder structure not working

Tags: yii

I'm relatively new to Yii. I've managed to get a sample application up and running but as I am now moving to a real project, I would like to use the following folder structure for increased security:

```
[Server root (/) ]
- yii
 -- framework
 -- requirements

[Server htdocs]
- myapp
 -- public
  --- assets
  --- css
  --- images
  --- themes
  --- index.php

 -- private
  --- protected
```

All is fine when I leave the protected folder inside the public folder but I don't want to do this.

The only way I can get it to work using my proposed structure is if I create a symlink inside the public folder pointing to the protected folder inside the private folder. If I reference it directly in the private folder it just gives me a blank page upon app load.

I've double checked my configuration paths and permissions.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure Yii to use the folders you want for your specific needs, eg. protected-folder, assets, themes, etc.

Have a look at "[The directory structure of the Yii project site](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/155/the-directory-structure-of-the-yii-project-site/)" for an example.

Comment: Thanks very much, I hadn't seen this page before. Hopefully this will allow me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your protected folder where you want, but you have to tell it to `index.php`. In your case, the line where it says:

```
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';
```

must say:

```
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/../private/protected/config/main.php';
```

And same in `index-test.php`

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I had already done this (and just did it again to make sure it was correct). Unfortunately I am still having the same problem. When I access the app in the browser I just see a blank page.

Comment: Actually I managed to get it to partially work (the path was INDEED wrong and was overlooked...) However none of the CSS or images load (presumably because they are in the public folder and there is a path I need to change somewhere for those?) Any ideas?

Comment: And do you have in your `index.php` the line defining `$yii` adjusted correctly? In your case: `$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../yii/framework/yii.php';`

Comment: Yes I do, but the CSS and images are not being rendered. How do I tell yii where to find them? The link provided in the other answer doesn't explain how to point to them.

Comment: You can define it in `protected/config/main.php`, in the `basePath` key. In your case something like:`'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR'.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'myapp'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'public'`

Comment: I will try that. Haven't got it to work yet but I'm thinking it's just a matter of getting the path correct.

Comment: You have to point to your server root directory. Is it `myapp`, `myapp/public` or the folder where `myapp` is?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source project called [Yii Boilerplate](https://github.com/clevertech/YiiBoilerplate) which proposes application structure for Yii to use in large projects that require scalability.